# How to return object when using `append` in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append, nonetype

i have a function to append a list, something like this:

```
def append_func(element):
    if xxxx:
        new_list.append(element)
    else:
        []
```

I have another function that uses `append_func()`:

```
def second_func(item):
  for i in item:
     append_func(i)
```

if i run :

```
new_list = []
second _func(item)
new_list
```

This will return the list i want, but i can't do `new_list = second _func(item)` because in this case `new_list` will be a `None`.

I understand that `append()` will return a `None` type, but i'd like to return the appended list so I can use in other places `result = second _func(xxx)`, what i have missed? Thanks.

Comment: What is the point of `else` statement in the first method? It does literally nothing.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, is there any particular reason for not using built-in list method of `.extend()` which does pretty much the same as `second_func()`? It still returns `None`, mind you.

Comment: @matszwecja `second_func()` in my question is just a very simple example, my actual function does some other more complex things, but i only want to know about the `append()` bit.

Comment: Why do you need to return `new_list` at all? It is a global variable that is mutated in the function. This is not really nice stylistically, but the changed data is globally available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the clarification you did in the comments you might want something like this. (I changed some of your placeholders so we have running code and a reproducible example)

The list is created by `second_func` so we get rid of the global list.

```
def append_func(data, element):
    if 2 < element < 7:
        data.append(element ** 2)


def second_func(items):
    new_list = []
    for i in items:
        append_func(new_list, i)
    return new_list


items = list(range(10))
result = second_func(items)
print(result)
```

The result is `[9, 16, 25, 36]`.

Answer (score 1):

simply tell python what to return:

```py
def append_func(element):
    if xxxx:
        new_list.append(element)
    else:
        []
    return new_list   # here, return whatever you want to return
```

if there is no "return" statement in the function, then the function returns `None`

Comment: This will not make `second_func` return anything.

Comment: @matszwecja obviously, the same advice applies to `second_func` -- you have to tell python what to return. Come on.

Answer (score 0):

The `new_list` you define before calling `second_func` is a global variable. Every time you call `second_func()` it will append the argument to the global variable. But the `new_list` is not restricted to the namespace of either function, so setting it as a return value doesn't make sense.

Comment: yes I find everytime I run the code, `new_list` is becoming bigger, is there a way to avoid this? - no matter how many times i run the code, `new_list` stays the say thing. (all I can think is to set `new_list=[]` everytime before i run the code, is there a better way?)

Comment: @wawawa "Do not use global variables" is a way to avoid this. And many other problems.

Comment: @matszwecja right, how can I do this if i don't use global variable? Could you provide a bit more details/code please?

Comment: @wawawa look at Matthias example for one way to do it. There is actually very good reason functions like `.append` and `.extend` from `list` do not return anything - You need the list you are appending to anyway, so returning it does not give you any additional information.